# Finding MyPagerAdapter object name in Android, how?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with a few fragments. The pageradapter is instantiated in FormActivity as so;

```
//initialise pager for swipe screens
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, I then need to access MyPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(), but I do not know what the object name for the adapter is, or how to retrieve it from, I guess, getSupportManager(), somehow?
Here is the viewpager code;

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("@string/form_instruct");
                case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
                case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
                case 3: return FourthFragment.newInstance("FourthFragment, Instance 1");
                //case 4: return FifthFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
                default: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Default");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            registeredFragments.remove(position);
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }

        public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
            return registeredFragments.get(position);
        }
    }
```

And the method in which I am calling the adapter.getRegisteredFragment()

```
public void DrawText() {
        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        if (user.size() != 0) {

            // Displaying the user details on the screen
            Fragment n = adapter.getRegisteredFragment(0);
            n.surnameText.setText(surname);

        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "table not filled");
        }
    }
```

Help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object for the view pager like this

```
public MyPagerAdapter adapter;
```

Then instantiate the object

```
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then to call the method do this

```
Fragment fragment = adapter.getRegisteredFragment(pager.getCurrentItem);
```

Comment: Sounds logical, however I'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol 'adapter' when calling adapter.getRegistered()
Code:

`public void DrawText() {`
       ` // Fetching user details from sqlite`
        `HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();`

        if (user.size() != 0) {

            // Displaying the user details on the screen
            Fragment n = adapter.getRegisteredFragment(0);
            n.surnameText.setText(surname);

        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "table not filled");
        }
    }``

Comment: Can you edit the questions with the updated code? Then I will have another look

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to access the EditText in there to update it...